# How to add a row in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Actually I am making a program which takes .properties file and show the value in GUI. I am already done with reading and writing. Now, at this point I dont how to implement this add/remove rows functionality. I want to add a row on run-time. I am using abstract table How can I add and Delete rows.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class StackoverflowStuff implements TableModelListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Vector> data = new Vector<>();
        String strState[] = new String[2];
        strState[0] = "Property";
        strState[1] = "value";
//        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(strState));

        String line;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/properties/spanish.properties");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), "=");

            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                Vector row = new Vector();
                row.addElement(st1.nextToken());
                data.add(row);
            }
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("###") && (line.contains("#"))) {
                    continue;
                }
                StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, "=");
                while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    Vector row1 = new Vector();
                    row1.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                    data.add(row1);

                }
                System.out.println("Selected ::  " + data);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//        final int rows = data.size();
//        System.out.println("Selected ::  " + data.size());
//        final int columns = 2;
//        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
//            int dataas;
//            dataas = data.size() - 1;
//            System.out.println("Selected ::  " + dataas);
//            if (dataas % 2 == 0) {
//                columnNames.add("Property");
//            } else {
//                columnNames.add("Value");
//            }
//        }

//        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
//            Vector row = new Vector();
//            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
//                row.add(j);
//            }
//            data.add(row);
//        }
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JButton saveBtn = new JButton("Save");

        JScrollPane jsPane;
        jsPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(jsPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(saveBtn);
        JButton addRowbtn = new JButton("Add Row");
        panel.add(addRowbtn, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        try {
            addRowbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

//                    myModel.setValueAt(table, table.getRowCount() + 1, 0);
//                    myModel.setValueAt(table, table.getRowCount(), 1);
                    System.out.println("sadasdasd");

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    try {
                        BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/properties/cwqesdb.properties"));
                        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                            bfw.newLine();
                            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                                if (j == 0) {
                                    bfw.write((String) (table.getValueAt(i, j)));
                                    System.out.println("Selected data: MouseDragged ::  " + table.getValueAt(i, j));

                                } else {
//                                    bfw.write((String) (table.getValueAt(i, j)));
//                                    bfw.write("=");
//                                    System.out.println("Selected data: MouseDragged ::  " + table.getValueAt(i, j));
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        bfw.flush();
                        bfw.close();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Successfully Saved.");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

here is my file contents
spanisch.properties

```
username=Benutzername
password=Kennwort
gender=Geschlecht
male=männlich
female=weiblich
age=alter
### ewflmkdsajfaef ####sdasdfasdf
asfsadfsimpleasdf ####
asdas = asdashdash
address=Anschrift
submit=einreichen
message=Erfolgreich abgegeben ...
```

Comment: Aside: You have a lot going on in the constructor of your table model. I would do all that stuff outside, ad just pass the model's constructor some data structure

Comment: 1. fireTableChanged is wrong notifier in addRow, 2. getValueAt contains strange code lines

Comment: Also I don't see anything in your model implementation that would cause you not to use `DefaultTableModel`, besides the file reading stuff, which I already proposed to take out of the model.

Comment: How it is possible then Can anybody correct this code please. I am beginner..

Comment: @peeskillet Kindly tell me how take out file reading stuff from the model.

Comment: Please see below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Kindly tell me how take out file reading stuff from the model"

In your model, you have two `Vectors`, one for the data, and one for the columns. Read the data to the vectors, then just create a `DefaultTableModel` with them. Though what may be messing you up, is that for the data you are using a single `Vector` for the data. The data should be two dimensional, so you would want a `Vector<Vector>`, just like if you were to use arrays for the data, it would be `Object[][] data`. So you may want to change your implementation to something like

```
Vector<Vector> data = new Vector<>();
Vector<String> columnName = new Vector();
...
while ((line = reader.nextLine()) != null) {
    Vector row = new Vector();
    // tokenize and add the `row`
    data.add(row);
}

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnsNames);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

---

See the [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) API documentation for more methods you can use to manipulate the data.

Here's a simple example

```
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class StackoverflowStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Vector> data = new Vector<>();
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();

        final int rows = 10;
        final int columns = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            columnNames.add("Col");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            Vector row = new Vector();
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                row.add(j);
            }
            data.add(row);
        }

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
    }  
}
```

If you later want to add a row to the model, you can simply use the [`addRow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object[]%29) method of `DefaultTableModel`, which is overloaded to accept a `Vector` or an `Object[]` array

---

### UPDATE

What you are doing is

```
Vector<Vector> data = new Vector();
while (... ) {
    while(...) {
       Vector row = new Vector();
       String data = ...
       row.add(data);
       data.add(row);
    }
}
```

You adding a new row for each token, when you should be creating the row vector outside the loop, and adding the tokens inside the loop, then adding the row outside the loop

```
Vector<Vector> data = new Vector();
while (... ) {
    Vector row = new Vector();
    while(...) { 
       String data = ...
       row.add(data);
    }
    data.add(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanku @peeskillet But now i got an error incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Vector while saving StringTokenizer to vector.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to create new `Vector` for each row and add that `Vector` the Vector<Vector>.  You may be trying to add a String to `Vector<Vector>`

Comment: here is [my code](http://pastebin.com/jVPJXaGA). I want to save the values as for example name=jawad I want to read this line and save "name" is column one and "jawad" in column 2.

Comment: I have a problem linking to pastebin. Edit your post with a snippet of the file

Comment: I  think you missed the part where I said I have a problem linking to pastebin. Edit your original post with a snippet of the file

Comment: Did you also miss the part about the file snippet. I don't know what the contents of the file looks like. name=jawad tells me nothing

Comment: You file has no consistent format whatsoever, so I won't even try anything with it. I can only suggest that you look at your logic. For each token, you are creating a Vector, adding one element to it, then adding the Vector to a the data Vector. Each Vector you add to the data Vector, will be a new row. Look at your code and debug using that knowledge

Comment: plus one, but table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize()); is only for reasonable numbers of columns & rows (success in this case)

Comment: @mKorbel Yeah I know I was going to post an image and didn't want to be to big, but then I got lazy and didn't post it :-)

Comment: @JawadSatti look at my example code. I create the Vector inside the loop that creates each row, and outside the loop that creates each column

Comment: Now I am getting this error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector. Can anybody please guide me. I am doing this final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);.